# Transforming mongoDb json file into SQL tables

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have a mongo DB Json file that I in some way want to squeeze into a SQL database and have it make sense but I don't know what that would look like. The file looks like this:

```
"_id":{
      "$oid":"61377659d24fd78398a5a54a"
   },
   "currentTotalValue":0,
   "stocks":[
      {
         "ticker":"TSLA",
         "baseCurrency":"USD",
         "numberOfShares":20
      },
      {
         "ticker":"GME",
         "baseCurrency":"USD",
         "numberOfShares":100
      },
      {
         "ticker":"KINV-B",
         "baseCurrency":"SEK",
         "numberOfShares":50
      },
      {
         "ticker":"BBD.B",
         "baseCurrency":"CAD",
         "numberOfShares":100
      },
      {
         "ticker":"NAS",
         "baseCurrency":"NOK",
         "numberOfShares":20000
      }
   ]
}
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"61377666d24fd78398a5a558"
   },
   "currentTotalValue":0,
   "stocks":[
      {
         "ticker":"TSLA",
         "baseCurrency":"USD",
         "numberOfShares":1
      },
      {
         "ticker":"GME",
         "baseCurrency":"USD",
         "numberOfShares":3457
      },
      {
         "ticker":"KINV-B",
         "baseCurrency":"SEK",
         "numberOfShares":3547
      },
      {
         "ticker":"BBD.B",
         "baseCurrency":"CAD",
         "numberOfShares":5768
      },
      {
         "ticker":"NAS",
         "baseCurrency":"NOK",
         "numberOfShares":100000
      }
   ]
}
```

So in SQL is this two separate tables with one portfolio in each or?
And if so what would those tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how one interprets the file. One could say, there are two portfolios which are described by some oid and a currentTotalValue two which the stocks belong to.

```
CREATE TABLE portfolios (
  oid VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  currentTotalValue INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE stocks (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  portfolio_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  ticker VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  baseCurrency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  numberOfShares INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_stocks_portfolios 
      FOREIGN KEY(portfolio_id) REFERENCES portfolios(oid)
);
```

If you don't need the portfolio you can drop it and remove the foreign key constraint from table stocks:

```
CREATE TABLE stocks (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  portfolio_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  ticker VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  baseCurrency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  numberOfShares INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Warning: this is just a rough sketch to get a basic idea. Depending on the used DBMS you could use an auto increment value for the stocks id.

Comment: Tbh I was thinking of the exact same way of laying it out. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. I accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear: this is not two separate tables with one portfolio in each but one table for all portfolios (if needed) and one table for all stocks.

Comment: Yes I know and I don't think there is any other way to make it make sense. As we are going from a non-relational db to a relational this is the only way imo.